# django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "N": syntax error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm getting some weird error when i run ./manage.py runserver or migrate command.
I checked the files from where the exception is thrown, but no idea

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fd4c73df488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 164, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 182, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 85, in __enter__
    self.atomic.__enter__()
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 190, in __enter__
    connection._start_transaction_under_autocommit()
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 299, in _start_transaction_under_autocommit
    self.cursor().execute("BEGIN")
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/dummy/RobocopEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 316, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "N": syntax error
```

Comment: This is an error in generated SQL. Can you add SQL logs?

Comment: Also, try running `./manage.py sqlmigrate` and looking at the output.

Comment: `DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS` is most likely your problem. Check here for a syntax error / typo.

Comment: I use sqlite, how do i get the logs?

Comment: I can run the same code in a different host and it works perfectly

Comment: @AmalTs I think this is a DB encoding issue. Can you check it with `PRAGMA encoding;` in your sqlite shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is python build with ucs-2, so rebuild with **ucs-4** should be work.

Python 2.7.6

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```